# Script to change multiple files to an executable simplification

Tags: linux, performance, shell, sh

I'm trying to create a script where I can change multiple files permissions. Some of the files are: .sh, .exe, .bat, etc. I already know  that I could use:

```
find ~/directory/ -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

With this line, I could change all the permissions of the files with .sh. I was wondering if there was a short cut or a more eloquent way to write the code where it could encompass all the other files in one line instead of just copying and pasting the line multiple times and changing what is in the quotations.

Comment: Try `-regex` instead of `-iname` (version dependent)

Comment: eg `-iregex '.*.py\|.*.sh'`

Answer (score 2):

According to my understanding, you are trying to change permission for multiple types of file. For that try this command

```
find ~/directory/ -type f \( -iname \*.sh -o -iname \*.exe -o -iname \*.bat  \) -exec chmod 111 {} \;
```

or

```
find ~/directory/ -type f -regex ".*\.\(sh\|bat\|exe\)" -exec chmod 111 {} \;
```

or you can add multiple type options by adding `-o -iname \*.extention_type` in between `()`.

Comment: that line runs just fine in the terminal, but when I run it in the script, I keep getting a "find: missing argument to '-exec'", I'm running the second code twice in a script but in different directories

Comment: I edited my answer. now above mention command will work in a script. problem was chmod command which was not accepting +x argument so i used chmod 111 instead of chamod +x.